# Android studio: is there a way to trigger intents without doing them?

Tags: android, android-intent, screen

I am trying to trigger the "android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF" and "android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON" for a broadcast receiver without actually physically turning the screen on and off. Is there a way to do this?

Ex: I press a button in my test app and then it triggers any broadcast receivers for turning the screen on and off despite the screen being on the whole time.

Comment: For a test, or for part of your production workflow?  Also, do you want other apps to also receive it, or are you just testing your app?

Comment: *screen being on the whole time* It doesn't make sens as Activity would be in paused state and should not "do" anything

Comment: For testing other apps with broadcast receivers.